# Is the druid boy Mordred?

Tags: merlin-bbc

Earlier in the series Merlin comes across a group of Druids and a young boy who telepathically talks to him and refers to his magical name "Emrys". on a few occasions when this boy is in danger the Dragon tell Merlin not to help him as the boy will one day ally himself with Morganna and pose a great threat to Arthur, a warning (like a fair few) Merlin ignores.

The final season is Mordred is introduced and at first Merlin seems fearful since Mordred knows his name as Emrys however at first Mordred shows he is on Arthur's side until he betrays the kingdom and allies with Morganna.

Now i am wondering, is Mordred the druid boy and if so, how many years have elapsed in the series since their first meeting?

Comment: Wasn't the druid boy actually called Mordred in one of the earlier episodes?

Comment: @Izkata when i first saw the series on TV i was being called to deal with technical issues on the internet so kept getting called away so it possible i missed that, however i could assume it was Mordred but Merlin and Arthur hadn't looked to have aged all that much in comparison and the Mordred here isn't a homunculus clone

Answer (score 3):

From the very last scene when he first appears in 1x08, "[The Beginning of the End](http://merlin.wikia.com/wiki/The_Beginning_of_the_End)":

> **Adult Druid:** "We are forever indebted to you, Arthur Pendragon, for returning the boy to us."
>
> **Arthur:** "You must not let it be known that it was I who brought him to you."
>
> **Adult Druid:** "We will tell no one.  You have my word."
>
> *(Starts to walk away)*
>
> **Arthur:** "Wait!  I don't even know your name.  At least tell me your name."
>
> *(Stops and looks back at Arthur)*
>
> **Adult Druid:** "It's all right."
>
> **Mordred:** "My name is Mordred."
>
> **Arthur:** "Good luck, Mordred."

As for Mordred's age, one fan [broke down the calendar references in the series](http://welcometocamelotrpg.proboards.com/thread/5130/bbc-merlins-episodic-timeline) to come up with 10 years passing between the start and end of the series.  The re-casting of Mordred from someone born in 1997 to someone born in 1988 makes a lot more sense in this case:

> - The Great Purge happened 20 years before Merlin came to Camelot, and right after Arthur's birth.
> - Year 1: Series 1
> - Year 2: Series 2
> - Year 3: One Year Gap
> - Year 4: Series 3
> - Year 5: One Year Gap
> - Year 6: Series Four
> - Year 7, 8, 9 : Three Year Gap
> - Year 10: Series Five

So although Season 5 aired 5 years after Season 1, the characters have all aged 10 years, and a 5-year-older Mordred would have been too young.  All the other actors were fine because at their age, a few missing years isn't as visible, but with how young Mordred was in his first appearance, the original actor wouldn't have aged enough.